# Why is this MySQL query slowing down my code

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

Currently I have a MySQL query I run in PHP and when going through the results I update the original table but a simple table with 500 rows takes 30 seconds to complete:

```
$sqlquery = mysql_query('SELECT id, special_data FROM stats_visits WHERE processed = 0');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)){ 
    $stat_id = $row['id'];
    // Make use of special_data field for some operations
    mysql_query('UPDATE stats_visits SET processed = 1 WHERE id = ' . $stat_id);
}
```

Is it because I am updating the table from which I am selecting? I've solved this by doing the following but because the table might have thousands of records in future I'm unsure how well the IN will hold up:

```
$statids = array();

$sqlquery = mysql_query('SELECT id, special_data FROM stats_visits WHERE processed = 0');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)){ 
    $statids[] = $row['id'];
    // Make use of special_data field for some operations
}

mysql_query('UPDATE stats_visits SET processed = 1 WHERE id IN(' . implode(',', $statids) . ')');
```

Comment: Why are you fetching all of the rows and updating by id instead of just updating based on the conditions you used in the SELECT?

Comment: In that select (I should probably have indicated this) I select more data, use it for processing and once used I need to indicate this by setting processed=1 so in the next run I can skip it.

Comment: If all you're doing is updating the `processed` column then theres no reason to run a `SELECT` and an `UPDATE` query. You can do it with the answer @Truth provided below. The other option is to use an array of edited data and combine everything into two queries.

Comment: You can also look into using temp tables and cross table updates -> http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/bulk-update-in-mysql-with-the-use-of-temporary-table/

Comment: I am not simply updating the column, I've edited my question indicate I select more data, use it and then once done I set that record as "processed".

Comment: The `IN (...)` will fail once the query string size reaches the mysql max_allowed_packet limit, which is the max byte-size a query string can be.

Comment: Yeah, as per Timothy's response I split the array into groups of 100 and run the queries on each which mitigates this potential issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version you're hitting the database once for every single update. This is normally a bad idea. The 2nd version is hitting the database once.

If you are concerned about how this will work out in the future, perhaps create a hybrid. Batch the updates up into groups of 100 and update them in blocks.

Comment: Batch sounds like a great idea - implemented it and works like a charm and no worries about queries being too long. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If all you want is to update all the records to being `processed = 1` Why not resolve it with a single query?:

```
UPDATE `stats_visits` SET `processed` = 1 WHERE `processed` = 0;
```

Comment: Because in that select (I should probably have indicated this) I select more data, use it for processing and once used I need to indicate this by setting processed=1 so in the next run I can skip it.

Comment: -1 If he does processing (as specified above) then you could accidentally mark records as processed that are not actually processed.

Comment: in the OPs query above all hes doing is selecting rows, and then updating those rows. Effectively doing what @Truth has stated is the same thing. This is the correct answer. Your other option is to combine this `UPDATE` with the `UPDATE` for your "processing" of "other data"..

Comment: You can also look into using temp tables and cross table updates -> http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/bulk-update-in-mysql-with-the-use-of-temporary-table/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to store all of the ids which need updating as an array then implode these into the query with the `IN` operator.

e.g.

```
$processedArray= array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)){ 
    $stat_id = $row['id'];
    //Your processing goes here
    $processedArray[] = $stat_id; //Store an id if it needs updating as processed
}

mysql_query('UPDATE stats_visits SET processed = 1 WHERE id IN ('.implode(',', $processedArray).')');
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.